Why is there an increased response times when fronting a Lambda with Cloudfront?
I have a simple Lambda function that is fronted by CloudFront. This Lambda also has a function URL.
Invoking the Lambda using the Function URL is way faster than invoking it via CloudFront. Based on my understanding of CloudFront, I'd have expected it to be much quicker.
I've created a small CloudFormation template to help reproduce this behaviour.
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Resources:
  LambdaExecutionRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: 'lambda.amazonaws.com'
            Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: 'LambdaExecutionPolicy'
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: 'logs:*'
                Resource: '*'

  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function'
    Properties:
      FunctionName: 'HelloWorldFunction'
      Runtime: 'nodejs18.x'
      Architectures: ['arm64']
      Handler: 'index.handler'
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaExecutionRole.Arn
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          exports.handler = async (event) => {
            return {
              statusCode: 200,
              body: 'Hello, World!',
            };
          };

  FunctionUrl:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Url'
    Properties:
      AuthType: NONE
      TargetFunctionArn: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunction.Arn

  LambdaPermission:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Permission'
    Properties:
      Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunctionUrl'
      FunctionName: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunction.Arn
      Principal: '*'
      FunctionUrlAuthType: 'NONE'

  CloudFrontDistribution:
    Type: 'AWS::CloudFront::Distribution'
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig:
        Enabled: true
        DefaultRootObject: ''
        Origins:
          - Id: 'LambdaOrigin'
            DomainName: !Select [2, !Split ['/', !GetAtt FunctionUrl.FunctionUrl]]
            CustomOriginConfig:
              HTTPPort: 443
              HTTPSPort: 443
              OriginProtocolPolicy: 'https-only'
        DefaultCacheBehavior:
          TargetOriginId: 'LambdaOrigin'
          ViewerProtocolPolicy: 'redirect-to-https'
          AllowedMethods:
            - GET
            - HEAD
          CachedMethods:
            - GET
            - HEAD
          ForwardedValues:
            QueryString: false
            Cookies:
              Forward: none
          CachePolicyId: '4135ea2d-6df8-44a3-9df3-4b5a84be39ad' # Managed policy for caching disabled
          OriginRequestPolicyId: 'b689b0a8-53d0-40ab-baf2-68738e2966ac' # Managed policy for all viewer except host header
        ViewerCertificate:
          CloudFrontDefaultCertificate: true

Outputs:
  FunctionUrl:
    Description: 'URL of the Lambda function'
    Value: !GetAtt FunctionUrl.FunctionUrl
    Export:
      Name: 'FunctionUrl'

  CloudFrontUrl:
    Description: 'URL of the CloudFront distribution'
    Value: !Sub 'https://${CloudFrontDistribution.DomainName}'
    Export:
      Name: 'CloudFrontUrl'

There are no caches, no VPC-based resources, no cross-region gotchas - this is as simple as it gets.
Here's a screenshot from Chrome where you can see the CloudFront requests taking over a second, while the Lambda URL ones, being one-third of that.

What could be the reason that the function URL outperforms the CloudFront distribution?

You add a layer of indirection, and wonder why it is slower than calling it directly?

I was under the impression that cf requests hit the nearest AWS PoP and then go over AWS's dedicated lines. It is possible that I've been misinformed all along Mark.

@MridangAgarwalla you aren't wrong.  CloudFront should not add this much latency and should be faster in some cases, depending on your geographic location and it's distance from the Lambda function location.  What's interesting here is the 4th invocation -- direct to the endpoint but still slow.  Is it possible that there is another factor at play?
